# How to verify a user on my app owns a youtube video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-authentication, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm building a chrome extension for youtube that can send a typed message to a user on my app (owner of the youtube video).

How can I determine if a user on my app (registered with google api) is an owner of a youtube video (with consent)?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add what have you tried. Did you manage to get the user of the app and check if the user has a YouTube channel?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried using youtube data api to request access from user to their youtube videos and it is successful at the task.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).